# SQL - Modify records to get total overall balance of quarters in one column even for specific quarter in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, where-clause, window-functions

I am working on a query where I have to have total balance of all quarter.
For e.g.

```
ID  NAME  Quarter BALANCE
1   RB    202010  500
1   RB    202020  200
2   AD    202020  100
3   KT    202020  800
3   KT    201910  699
```

I got the below using sum(balance) over(partition by ID) TOTAL_BALANCE -

```
 ID  NAME  Quarter BALANCE TOTAL_BALANCE
 1   RB    202010  500     700
 1   RB    202020  200     700
 2   AD    202020  100     100
 3   KT    202020  800     1499
 3   KT    201910  699     1499
```

Now I need a result if I use filter on Quarter like quarter = '202020' It should give -

```
ID  NAME  Quarter BALANCE TOTAL_BALANCE
1   RB    202020  200     700
2   AD    202020  100     100
3   KT    202020  800     1499
```

but because of using Group by 'Balance' as required for partition function I am getting -

```
  ID  NAME  Quarter BALANCE TOTAL_BALANCE
  1   RB    202020  200     200
  2   AD    202020  100     100
  3   KT    202020  800     800
```

Comment: Given the information.  How do you think people can help you???  Please read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions *in a subquery*, and then filter in the outer query:

```
select *
from (select t.*, sum(balance) over(partition by id) total_balance from mytable t) t
where quater = '2020'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
  select ID,NAME,Quarter,BALANCE,
     (select sum(balance) over(partition by ID) from tablename t1 where t.id=t1.id) as total_balance
  from tablename t where quarter = '202020'
```

Comment: There is an error saying - single row sub-query returns more than one row